# Maven commands resuting in Killed: 9 on MAC OS

Tags: macos, maven, sudo

```
WIN201-S9L:psg 201$ mvn -version
Killed: 9

WIN201-S9L:psg 201$ sudo mvn -version
Password:
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-18T00:03:14+05:30)
Maven home: /Library/apache-maven-3.5.4
```

For some reason mvn command works with sudo and result in "Killed: 9" without sudo. I am new to **mac PC Cataline** not sure what could be the issue?

Comment: I end up re-imaging mac as nothing else worked.